# Ist die Katze aus dem Haus... Der Platz des Verbs

Tags: word-order

Warum ist im Sprichwort "Ist die Katze aus dem Haus, tanzen die Mäuse" das Verb "ist" auf dem ersten Platz? Ich dachte das Verb fängt einen Satz nur in Fragen an.

Comment: Zum Thema siehe (auf Englisch): https://german.stackexchange.com/q/17355/35111 Finde leider keine passende Frage auf Deutsch.

Comment: Siehe auch https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/56479/can-the-verb-come-first-when-theres-no-subordinate-clause Ich konnte auch keine Frage auf Deutsch finden.

Comment: Eine Suche nach "uneingeleiteter Nebensatz" liefert noch mehr Fragen, aber in der Tat alle auf Englisch.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In selbständigen Sätzen zeigt die [Verberststellung](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/V1-Stellung) (V1) an, daß es sich um eine Entscheidungs- oder Ja-Nein-Frage handelt.

> Ist die Katze aus dem Haus? – Nein, sie ist im Haus.

Aber in Sätzen, die in einen anderen Satz eingebettet sind, signalisiert Verberststellung [konditionale](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bedingungssatz) Bedeutung. Die Tatsache, daß der Satz eingebettet ist, erkannt man am finiten Verb an Position 2. Der Verberstsatz besetzt die Position 1 des Hauptsatzes.

> Ist die Katze aus dem Haus, **tanzen** die Mäuse.

Da die Bedeutung konditional ist, bietet sich zur Umschreibung ein Nebensatz mit *wenn* an.

> Wenn die Katze aus dem Haus ist, tanzen die Mäuse.

Comment: Beantwortest kaum die Frage nach dem "Warum?". Zwar muss man nicht jeder Frage ein "Woher?" unterstellen. Es ist aber bemerkenswert, dass doch SVO am wahrscheinlichsten als Grundstruktur der Ursprache Indogermanisch gilt--bzw. VO mit klitischem Subjekt. Dass der erste in den zweiten Satz eingebettet ist, mag einleuchtend sein. Man findet aber auch *Kiekste nochmal so, gibts ein Paar hinter die Leffel*, das eher imperativ anmutet (*guck nicht so doof, sonst ...*), mit *Sei ...* etwa auch Konjunktiv, so auch *wird* bzw. *würd*. Manche Sprachen (bspw. Finnisch) kennen sogar Konditional-Flektion.

Answer (score 0):

It's a variaton of "Wenn die Katze aus dem aus ist, tanzen die Mäuse auf dem Tisch" It's less common.

swapping subordinate clause and main clause wouldn't work in your example. While you can say "Die Mäuse tanzen auf dem Tisch, wenn die Katze aus dem Haus ist." the sentence "Die Mäuse tanzen auf dem Tisch, ist die Katze aus dem Haus" would sound wierd.

Comment: Wäre die Frage nicht auf deutsch gewesen, wäre sie als Duplikat geschlossen worden, denn wir haben mehrere englische Fragen zu dem Thema. Daher ist eine englische Antwort hier nicht wirklich hilfreich.

Comment: Willkommen bei German.SE. Da die Frage insgesamt auf Deutsch gestellt ist, bitte die eigene Antwort auch auf Deutsch posten. Danke.